# Ошибка System.InvalidOperationException: 'Splitter/consolidator worker encountered exception while consuming source data' в ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

Получаю исключение **Splitter/consolidator worker encountered exception while consuming source data**, в чем может быть проблема? Почему данные с файла считаются ошибочными?

```
IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ImageData>(path: _trainTagsTsv,
                                                                    separatorChar: '\t',
                                                                    hasHeader: false);

ITransformer model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData); //Вот тут InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Проверь данные в файле

- В конце файла возможно есть `\t` или `\n`, убедись, что файл не имеет лишних символов.
- Внимательно посмотри на разделение столбцов в файле и в коде. Значение по умолчанию - `\t` (см. код в вопросе на параметр `separatorChar`). Вероятно, в твоем файле столбцы разделяются другим `char` символом.
- Твой файл битый. Отсортируй папку по размеру файлов и удали те, которые весят 0 Кб.

Я всё сделал, но ошибка осталась. В чем проблема!?

#### Проверь входные параметры в коде

- На данный момент минимальное значение для высоты и ширины сжатия изображения - `224`.

Можно установить Netron, чтобы посмотреть на свою модель. Вы увидите, что на первом слое будет стоять что-то вроде 224x224x3. Модель привязана к этому входному разрешению, потому что она обучается на большом наборе данных именно в этом разрешении. Вы можете изменить входной слой, например, с помощью keras.

Вот тут будет `InvalidArgumentError: Computed output size would be negative`:

```
EstimatorChain<T>.Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(imageWidth: 64, imageHeight: 64)
```

А вот так правильно:

```
EstimatorChain<T>.Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(imageWidth: 224, imageHeight: 224))
```